# On a Pythagorean-type equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $a,b,c,d$ are distinct noninteger rational numbers. If

$a^{2}b - c^2 = d^2$

Should $b$ be necessarily a square in $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: don't really need to specify the not 1 part if nothings an integer.

Comment: Oh nice observation @shai, thanks !

Comment: Did you even try to plug in *one* single test case? Such as $c=\frac12$, $d=\frac13$, $a=\frac14$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $a=\frac14$, $b=\frac{52}9$, $c=\frac12$, $d=\frac13$, we have four distinct non-integer rationals fulfilling the equation, but $b$ is not a square.

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessarilly. If you set $a = 3/2, c = 2/3, b = 8784/18225, d = 4/5$ , then:

$a^2 b - c^2 = \frac{9}{4}\cdot\frac{8784}{18225} - \frac{4}{9} = \frac{19764}{18225} - \frac{9}{4} = \frac{16}{25} = d^2$

Comment: But $a$ and $c$ are not *distinct*, as specified in the question..?

Comment: My bad! I'm fixing this asap.

Answer (score 0):

$b=(d^2+c^2/a^2)$ when we take the square root its clear that the denominator is always the rational number a, now we just need to worry about the numerator, in general this would not be a square so would not have a rational square root, the d and c that would make a rational b are famous for being parts of Pythagorean triplets.